# KQL for date range

Tags: date-time, query

I've a managed property datetime and i try to use a search for having the result in range.
The issue is that i don't know how to format the date

```
myManageProperty=01/02/2014..17/02/2014
```

but i don't receive any result while i'm sure having result.
I suppose the format is not correct but where can i found the format i've to use?

thanks for you advices

Answer (score 6):

Try the following format `YYYY/MM/DD`

Here is an example.

`myManageProperty=2014/01/02..2014/02/17`

Ref: [Problem in KQL with date times and client object model in Sharepoint](http://sadomovalex.blogspot.com/2013/07/problem-in-kql-with-date-times-and.html)